# "how to include '\' in preg_replace() "

Tags: php

I want to include '\' in preg_replace(),but I can't do that. Here is what I tried:

```
 <?php 
        echo preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9 +  .\- \\  ]/",'',"<b>jjfjfj^</b>_+----\\\\.");
    ?>

Output:

    bjjfjfjb+----.
But I want this:
 bjjfjfjb+----\\\\.
```

Comment: You don't have an ending `/` after your regex and could you give us a sample of inputs and expected outputs?

Comment: what are you expecting ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\` has to be escaped for the regex **and** again because it's in a PHP string.

This means that in order to match a single `\` in regex in PHP, you need to type `\\\\` in your code.

Note that the PHP escaping applies to your search string as well -- it currently contains `\\\\`, but if you want four backslashes (per your required output) then you'll need to double each of them up to escape them.